# How to paste a serial key automatically

Tags: c#, winforms, clipboard

I have a serial key in this form

```
xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx
```

So, 5 `textboxes` in my c# windows application. When I copy full serial (5x5) to first `textbox` from some for example word document or notepad file, I want to fill 4 left `textboxes` automatically. How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this winforms or wpf?

Comment: winforms @ScottChamberlain

Comment: Your question was marked as duplicate, if you have a solution that is different than the other answers in the duplicate post your solution to the problem there.

Comment: @JackDawson don't forget it's possible to right-click paste, or hit `shift`+`insert` instead. Read the linked duplicate for a better solution.